# Forcing to read the Quran

Tags: quran, sharia, parents, children, human-rights

My parents are Huffaz الحمد لله and they want me to practice the Quran as well, I love the Quran, but I do not like being compelled to read it, because I would only see the efforts of my parents and not the efforts of myself. My parents always tell me to take the Qur'an and read it, memorize, and then do تسميع to them, wgich means they test me with what I memorized at a specific time, but this time doesnt really go with the way my schedule goes. i am also not comfortable with this because I have exams coming up and my studies are getting harder, so I need to manage my time by myslef in order to know when I can do something and when I cannot. Not only do I not want to be tested by someone with what I memorized, I also do not want someone to tell me when to take the Qur'an because I know when I should takethe Qur'an and read, because I am grown-up enough to know. But they still want them to test me and tell me when to take the Qur'an when I don't want it. If I don't do as they say, they will be angry with me and will not talk to me.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Sorry but what is your question?

Answer (score -1):

Salaam,
I think it is best if you sit down with your parents and have a discussion. Let them know how them forcing you to read Quran is straining your relationship with the Quran. The prophet (saw) never forced anyone to do anything, and that is how it should be. Islam is simple and beautiful and the way to get closer to the Quran and Islam should be on your own terms. I do believe that you should dedicate everyday to practice reading Quran, but don't stress yourself out. Some days, you should read a page, but even if you don't have time, reading even one verse a day will help you get closer to Allah (swt). We should always make time for our Creator who created time. I learned this from experience because I used to force myself to read a certain number of pages a day, and all it did was stress me out and made me frustrated. I thought to myself...the Quran is meant to do the complete opposite. One of my friends told me to start reading however much I felt. Some days, it was a page and some days it was one verse. This made me even close to the Quran, and much more in peace. Remember, from one verse, your can learn so much. Ponder about its meaning. I hope that this helps, and I pray that your parents allow you to practice your faith in a way that brings your peace and tranquility. Hope that helps. :) --MuslimGap

Comment: Jazakallahu khair. Thanks!